# Best way to show a value from an async function in html (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I have a DB with a 2 separate collections. a collection of games and a collection of comments about those games. each game has a unique ID and each comment has a field game_id and a unique ID.

I want to show a list of games with the number of comments for each game.

I wrote an async function in the scope that retrieves the number of comments for a game from the db and return a promise. what is the right (and most cleanest) way to show the value in the HTML ?

I do not want to include the comments counter in the games request because I want to cache the response for the games. so if a user navigates back to the games page, the list of games will be loaded immediately, and the comments numbers will be loaded after a few seconds. In addition, I want to do as few server side CPU usage as possible.

Will this code work?

```
//code in HTML
<div ng-repeat="game in games">
<span>{{game.date}}</span>
<span>{{game.home}}</span>
<span>{{game.away}}</span>
<span>{{getNumberOfComments(game.id)}} Comments</span>  
</div>

//code in script.js
app.factory('apiService', function($http) {
  return {
    getGames: function() {
      return $http.get('/api/games',{cache: true});
    },
   getCommentsCount: function(game_id) {
      return $http.get('/api/CommentsCount/' + id);
    }
  };
});


app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, apiService) {
  //get games from server when user enter the website
  gameService.getGames().then(function(resp) {
        $scope.games = resp.data;
  });
 //function that send a request from the server for a specific game about the number of comments.
 $scope.getNumberOfComments = function(id){ 
     return apiService.getCommentsCount(id).then(function(resp){
       return resp.data;
  });
 });
});
```

My server endpoints are only '/api/games' that sends the respond with a list of games. and /api/CommentsCount/:game_id, that sends the number of comments for a game. I do not want to change the way the server works for performance reasons.

Comment: 1, Use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki). 2. [Resolve](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) the dependencies (Games and comments) BEFORE entering the state. 3. [Cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) the results after the server reponed

Comment: I dont want to resolve the comment count before the page is loaded, because I dont want the user to wait untill all the information is loaded. I want to load the games from the cache (if available) and then present the games to the user. and then after the games are loaded, I want to load the comment count for each game. My problem is that there are 20-30 games and I need to load 20-30 comment counts.